# svn: forget about deleted files

Tags: svn

I did the following in an svn working copy I had:

```
sheep@sheepbox# gvim Dual_On_Off_Model.h
sheep@sheepbox# gvim Dual_On_Off_Model.cpp
(... made the files, saved them ...)
sheep@sheepbox# svn add Dual_On_Off_Model.*
sheep@sheepbox# svn st
M    Multiple_On_Off_Model.h
A    Dual_On_Off_Model.h
A    Dual_On_Off_Model.cpp
sheep@sheepbox# rm Dual_On_Off_Model.*    <- Stupid on my part, but discovered
                                          <-  I didn't need the class
```

So later:

```
sheep@sheepbox# svn st
M    Multiple_On_Off_Model.h
!    Dual_On_Off_Model.h
!    Dual_On_Off_Model.cpp
sheep@sheepbox# svn commit
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/home/sheep/src/secret_project_x/trunk/superduperd/Dual_On_Off_Model.h' is
scheduled for addition, but is missing
```

Basically, I deleted the files from my working copy without using svn rm, and now svn is mad because it can't find the files.

Since I don't need Dual_On_Off_Model.* and they have now gone to the big HDD in the sky, is there a way I can use a [Jedi mind trick](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_trick#Force_persuasion) on the working copy to have it stop yelling at me?

Comment: @Manuel Aldana - Tried your modified answer, definitely worked.  Post again, you'll get selected as best answer, cuz it doesn't require bash-fu or creating files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDITED BETWEEN:

use:

`svn revert -R .`

it reverts to the svn revision you have as local copy.

Comment: sorry, forgot it: have a try with -R option (I also corrected the answer text)

Comment: This worked for my scenario, but for directories that i had deleted it did not restore the .svn subdirectory (though it did restore the actual files, oddly enough).  This means that when i ran svn status, it gave a '?' next to these directories.  I deleted the directories in question (using rm -rf) and ran svn up and everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 6):

Just re-add the files (or empty files with those names) then delete them, using svn rm.

Answer (score 2):

`svn revert *` fails because `*` expands to every file in the directory, and you need to revert a file that's no longer in the directory.  Try `svn revert Dual_On_Off_Model.h Dual_On_Off_Model.cpp` instead.

To revert absolutely everything, you can use a bit of bash-fu:

```
svn status | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn revert
```

Grab the second word out of each line of `svn status`'s output (assuming you have no spaces in your filenames...), then pass those as arguments to `svn revert`.

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by Josh Kelley's answer:

```
svn st | awk '$1 == "!" {print $2}' | xargs svn revert
```

should fix an entire tree that has this problem.